# C++ Double Dispatch problems

Tags: c++, double-dispatch

This is part 2 to a problem I previously asked: [Is it possible to have polymorphic member overloading in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665602/is-it-possible-to-have-polymorphic-member-overloading-in-c)

Using the Wiki example I created this example.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

My problem is that the compiled code never looks up the vtable, and always uses the base instead of the inherited class.  Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

class xEntity;
class xVehicle;

class xMapObject
{
  public:
    virtual void Bump(xMapObject&) { std::cout << "MapObject Bump MapObject\n"; };
    virtual void Bump(xEntity&) { std::cout << "MapObject Bump Entity\n"; };
    virtual void Bump(xVehicle&) { std::cout << "MapObject Bump Vehicle\n"; };
};

class xEntity : public xMapObject
{
  public:
    virtual void Bump(xMapObject&) { std::cout << "Entity Bump MapObject\n"; };
    virtual void Bump(xEntity&) { std::cout << "Entity Bump Entity\n"; };
    virtual void Bump(xVehicle&) { std::cout << "Entity Bump Vehicle\n"; };
};

class xVehicle : public xEntity
{
  public:
    virtual void Bump(xMapObject&) { std::cout << "Vehicle Bump MapObject\n"; };
    virtual void Bump(xEntity&) { std::cout << "Vehicle Bump Entity\n"; };
    virtual void Bump(xVehicle&) { std::cout << "Vehicle Bump Vehicle\n"; };
};

int main(int argv, char **argc)
{
    xEntity Entity;
    xVehicle Vechile;

    xMapObject &EntityRef = Entity;
    xMapObject &VehicleRef = Vechile;

    VehicleRef.Bump(EntityRef);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the output is always:

```
Vehicle Bump MapObject
```

Any help on this mystery is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only did single dispatch, not double dispatch. The idea is that in `xVehicle`, taking an `xMapObject&`, you would call `ref.bump(*this);` which *is* double dispatch.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!

Comment: I needed to wait for the timer to expire.

Comment: @Shawn: Keep forgetting about that

Answer (score 1):

It is using the vtable; that's why it's calling `xVechicle::Bump()`!  The vtable isn't used on arguments, that doesn't make sense (in C++, at least).

The typical solution is to have e.g. `Bump(xMapObject& obj)` call `obj.Bump(*this);`.

Answer (score 1):

Is a bad design the xEntity::Bump(xVehicle&) because you are using as parameter in a base class a derived class.

and at least that your contract change, you don't need redefine base **Bump** methods.

the problem is that you are creating the **xMapRef** vars, that convert your **derived** class to a base class.

if you want that appropriated method is called, just call with the derived class object

Comment: It was just for testing purposes, following Wiki's example. It has been changed in the actual version.